# Make constructor parameters public in subclass

Tags: scala

I want the protected fields of a class to be made publicly visible in a subclass:

```
class MyClass(protected val someDao: SomeDao)

class TestMyClass extends MyClass(mock[SomeDao])
```

Now I want to access `someDao` like so:

```
val testClass = new TestMyClass
testClass.someDao
```

I've read that in Java and Scala access modifiers can be broadened but not restricted in subclasses (although these are just constructor parameters, not private fields per se). How can I achieve that in this example?

**EDIT**:
The answers provided suggest making `someDao` public in the base class. This is not what I want. I want it to remain private, but just change its visibility to public in the `TestMyClass` class.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, an overriden `val` cannot access the super implementation.

If you can modify the base class, one solution is to explicitely define an accessor method, which can be overriden; something like this:

```
class MyClass(_someDao: SomeDao) {
  protected def someDao = _someDao
}

class TestMyClass extends MyClass(mock[SomeDao]) {
  override def someDao = super.someDao
}
```

If you cannot change the base class, one workaround would be to define a public accessor method with a different name:

```
class MyClass(protected val someDao: SomeDao)

class TestMyClass extends MyClass(mock[SomeDao]) {
  def someDao2 = someDao
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `var` or `val` to parameters declaration:

```
class MyClass(val someDao: SomeDao)
```

In this case only *getter* function will be generate for `someDao` field. So when you write `testClass.someDao` you retrieve not the `someDao` as field you use their *getter* function.

Good example about visibility of class parameters in Scala demostrated at this [article](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-class-examples-constructors-case-classes-parameters#The_visibility_of_class_parameters).

#### Regarding to your last updates

Set [**package scope**](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-control-scala-method-scope-object-private-package#Package_scope) for parameter declaration:

```
class MyClass(private[lastPackageOfSomeDao] val someDao: SomeDao)
```